# Custom html as script src

Tags: html, src

I have a custom html (not js) file, but it wont let me use it as a script src:

```
function(){
    var ctx;
    function setupCanvas(setupVariable){
        ctx=setupVariable;
    };
    function circ(x,y,lps,wps,fill,outline){
        if(outline===true){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,lps, wps,6.28);
            ctx.stroke();
        };
        if (fill===true){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,lps,wps,6.28);
            ctx.stroke();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Move it into a js file and use it that way. Not as an html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Inline

Wrap the script in `<script>` tags like so:

```
<script>
function(){
    var ctx;
    function setupCanvas(setupVariable){
        ctx=setupVariable;
    };
    function circ(x,y,lps,wps,fill,outline){
        if(outline===true){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,lps, wps,6.28);
            ctx.stroke();
        };
        if (fill===true){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,lps,wps,6.28);
            ctx.stroke();
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

and put it in your html file.

## External

The `src` attribute of `<script>` is used to refer to `.js`. If you want to use an external script file, make a `script.js` file then include it in the html as:

```
<script src="http://example.com/script.js"></script>
```

replacing the src url with the location of your `script.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

The browser needs to know that the script source file contains nothing but javascript code, so it won't accept anything but a .js file. Your best option would be to factor out the javascript into its own .js file and include that wherever you need it.

If the js functions need the associated html to work, you'll need to wrap it in `document.write()` calls or something similar to make it palatable to the browser.